# Displaying documents with ability to edit online

Tags: javascript, node.js, document, documentviewer

I'm using [Node-ViewerJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-viewerjs) to display documents of different formats in my nodejs based web app. But besides pdf, ViewerJs only supports `Open Document` Format.

Is there any other good solution for displaying documents of different formats (i.e. doc, docx, xls, xlsx) preferably with ability to do online editing to the document by web viewers?

PS: I'm looking for some completely self-hosted or offline (in other words) solution rather than cloud based solutions.

Comment: I get many search results for (jquery/js/nodejs based) pdf viewers but why no body worked on other doc formats like .doc, .docx, .xls, .ppt, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try uploading your documents to google drive you can also do it via it's api's.

Then generate an embedded link of it, by following steps: *(After importing in google docs)*

1. File > Publish to the Web..;
2. Check the box that says “Automatically republish when changes are made”;
3. Click "Start Publishing";
4. Change “Get a link to the published data” from “Web page” to “HTML to embed in a page”;
5. Copy and paste the HTML code generated into your HTML webpage. it's basically an iframe so it will embed the google docs view in your webpage.

Comment: thanks for your answer but sorry i forgot mentioning that i need some self-hosted solution rather than some cloud based or online solution.